# Function F is not resistant to collisions

Tags: collision-resistance

If we have the following block cipher, **E(k,m)**, why is **f(x,y)** not collision resistant?
$$f(x,y) = E(y,x) \oplus y$$

Comment: Hint: What is something you can do knowing a ciphertext block and a key?

Comment: yes, i familiar with block cipher and stream cipher and know a bit about hash and it's properties like collision (weak,strong). in this example, it's using an encryption function as compression function but i don't know how do i show the f(x,y) isn't collision resistant.

Comment: And I gave you a hint why that might be.

Comment: so i don't get it. do you mean i must decryption to prove it ? would you please explain more detail

Comment: Imagine you are given $c=E(y,x)\oplus y$ and $y$. How would you go about recovering x? What happens if you use $y'\neq y$ instead?